# Как закрыть динамически созданный элемент по клику вне его области?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Событие навешено на `document`, который, соответственно, уже существовал до динамической загрузки элементов на страницу.
Данный код с существующим элементом работает, а с вновь добавленным нет:

```
$(document).on('click', function (event) {
    var buttonUlR = $('.button-ul-region');
    var ulButtonR = buttonUlR.find('.add-ul-button');
    if (!buttonUlR.is(event.target) && buttonUlR.has(event.target).length === 0) {
        ulButtonR.hide();
    }
});
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите в чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Вопрос про динамически добавленный элемент.

Comment: в чем принципиальная разница? Единственное что тебе надо сделать - проверить что ты не попал в нужный элемент - пример этого как раз есть в вопросе-дубликате. Там и код практически тот же самый

Comment: Вопрос не про то как скрыть элемент кликнув за его пределы. Данный код проверяет это и прекрасно работает с изначально существующим на странице элементом. Но с динамически добавленным с точно такой же разметкой и селекторами не работает. Второй аналогичный селектор вообще не находиться.

Comment: А я говорю, что работает. Приведи пример, в котором у тебя что-то не работает. В противном случае это полнейший дубликат

Comment: Вам нужно привести пример с разметкой и с кодом создания элемента, чтобы можно было найти ошибку

Comment: Оказалось все просто. Изначально обрабатываемые селекторы были по id. Позднее их поменяли на классы. Поменяли везде, кроме подгружаемого блока. А в панели разработчика не сразу удалось заметить, что в одном блоке название селектора это - класс, а в другом (подгружаемом) - id.